# Binding to Selected Feature ESRI/WPF Runtime/MVVM

Tags: arcgis-runtime, arcgis-runtime-sdk-wpf, model-view-viewmodel, databinding

Given a ArcGISLocalFeatureLayer as a layer on the WPF runtime map object, how can I bind a ViewModel to the selected feature or graphic?

```xml
<esri:ArcGISLocalFeatureLayer x:Name="MySampleLayer" ID="MyFeatures" 
Path="C:/..../Samples.mpk" LayerName="MyFeatures" OutFields="*" DisableClientCaching="True" 
Editable="True" AutoSave="False"  ValidateEdits="True" 
Mode="OnDemand"  SelectionColor="#FFFFFF00" />
```

I realize there is already a FeatureDataGrid and FeatureDataForm in the runtime, but I'm trying to achieve a little different user experience. For simplicity, suppose I just have some controls on the same window as the map:

```xml
<Grid >
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.DataContext>
            <local:FeaturePropertiesViewModel/>
        </StackPanel.DataContext>
        <TextBox Text="{Binding FeatureName}" />
        <TextBox Text="{Binding FeatureInfo}" />
    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

and a simple ViewModel ...

```cs
class FeaturePropertiesViewModel  
{
    public string FeatureName { get; set; }
    public string FeatureInfo { get; set; }

    public Graphic SelectedFeature { get; set; }     // ??? use this somehow?
    public GraphicCollection AllGraphics { get; set; }  // ??? use this somehow? 
}
```

How do I get those text fields updated to when a new feature is selected? Ideally, I'd like two-way binding so that changing the text updates the underlying feature class.

**Update:** Based on Darlene's suggestion, I started looking into other ways to get the information include the mouse interactions - since that is how the feature is being selected.

I can capture/handle the MouseLeftButtonDown event and do everything I need to in the code-behind. So I started working of that to refactor to MVVM. Using MvvmLight, I can map that event to a command like this:

```xml
<esri:ArcGISLocalFeatureLayer ... />

            <i:Interaction.Triggers>
                <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseLeftButtonDown">
                    <cmd:EventToCommand Command="{Binding Path=MyLeftMouseCommand, 
                     Source={StaticResource MyVieModel}}" 
                     CommandParameter="{Binding  RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=esriLocal:ArcGISLocalFeatureLayer}}"
                     PassEventArgsToCommand="False" />
                </i:EventTrigger>
            </i:Interaction.Triggers>
</esriLocal:ArcGISLocalFeatureLayer>
```

However, I need both the mouse event args (GraphicMouseButtonEventArgs) and the selected graphic. And I'm having trouble getting both passed to a command. I tried RelayCommand like this ...

```cs
public RelayCommand<ArcGISLocalFeatureLayer> MyLeftMouseCommand{ get; protected set; }
```

In constructor ...

```cs
    MyLeftMouseCommand= new RelayCommand<ArcGISLocalFeatureLayer>(p =>
    {
        Console.Writeline("It works!");
    });
```

And that will get me the CommandParameter value if I set PassEventArgsToCommand="False", or I can get GraphicMouseButtonEventArgs if I set PassEventArgsToCommand="True", but I can't get them at the same time!

Also using ReactiveUI if there is anything in there that might be helpful.

Comment: Well it looks like the behavior with PassEventArgsToCommand is expected behavior...  
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9101957/eventtocommand-issue-in-mvvm-light

Comment: Thanks! I'm looking at your code and trying to digest it all to see if/how I can integrate it.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good question.  I believe that the answer to your question is that there is not an easy way to do this.  I think what you are hoping for (and what I would like to work) is

```xml
<esri:ArcGISLocalFeatureLayer SelectedGraphic={Binding SelectedFeature}.../>
```

Unfortunately, there is not anything like this that I know of.  The layer (graphics or feature) has a SelectedGraphics collection, but that only has a getter so you cannot bind to an ObservableCollection on your view model of selected graphics. Have you posted this on the [ArcGIS Runtime Forums](http://forums.arcgis.com/forums/131-arcgis-for-wpf-sdk)?

How is the feature or graphic getting selected?  I think whatever logic you have written that selects the graphic will have to raise some kind of event and explicitly set the ViewModel.SelectedFeature (or vice versa - raise an event and explicitly call Graphic.Select when SelectedFeature changes).

[Fody's PropertyChanged](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged) can do a lot of this for you.  If the FeatureName and FeatureInfo depend on the value of the SelectedFeature you can look at the DependsOn or AlsoNotifyFor [attributes](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/Attributes).

If you want to do extra processing when a property changes (such as updating the stored feature) you could use [On_PropertyName_Changed](https://github.com/Fody/PropertyChanged/wiki/On_PropertyName_Changed).

```cs
[ImplementPropertyChanged]
public class FeaturePropertiesViewModel  
{
    [DependsOn("SelectedFeature")]
    public string FeatureName { get; set; }
    [DependsOn("SelectedFeature")]
    public string FeatureInfo { get; set; }

    public Graphic SelectedFeature { get; set; }     
    public GraphicCollection AllGraphics { get; set; }   

    public void OnFeatureInfoChanged(){
        //Update your feature
    }

    public void OnFeatureNameChanged(){
        //Update your feature
    }
}
```

Comment: I have posted on the ArcGIS forums. Still no solution. The feature is getting selected via left mouse click event on the layer. Then I'm just setting e.Graphic.Selected = true. Right now, this is in code-behind, but I want to move it to an ICommand instead. I can actually map the PropertyChanged method on the layer to an ICommand (whole different subject), but the command doesn't receive the sender as a parameter. The regular code-behind callback for layer.PropertyChanged does include the sender. My current workaround is using the code-behind callback, but I want MVVM and databinding.

Comment: Have you looked at using MouseBindings to bind your mouse gesture to an ICommand (this will work with .Net 4, but not 3.5).  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.mousebinding.aspx

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I've updated the question to reflect new progress.

Comment: I still don't think there is a pure MVVM way to do what you're wanting.  Since you always use the same ArcGIS Feature Layer maybe you don't need that as a command parameter and you can keep a reference to that layer in your ViewModel.  Then your RelayCommand can take the MouseEventParameters or your view's code behind can just pass the x,y screen coordinates to a method in your ViewModel.  There could be good reasons not to pass UI Event Args (such as MouseEventArgs) to your view model (easier unit testing).

Answer (score 1):

I posted to this at Esri's forums some ideas to this but to be short here is my approach for databinding issue since in real apps I don't define ViewModels as static resources in Views (usually my ViewModels are injected to Views by DI container + framework combination).

Use DataContextProxy for Wpf like described at http://kajanus.net/?p=15 (WinRT/SL version is blogged in here : http://kajanus.net/?p=387)

```cs
public class DataContextProxy : Freezable
{
    #region Overrides of Freezable

    protected override Freezable CreateInstanceCore()
    {
        return new DataContextProxy();
    }

    #endregion

    public object Data
    {
        get { return (object)GetValue(DataProperty); }
        set { SetValue(DataProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty DataProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("Data", typeof(object), typeof(DataContextProxy), new UIPropertyMetadata(null));
}
```

In ViewModel you need to have collection and selected properties (like you already have) and then you can bind those as you want in your View.

The binding goes like this:

```xml
<Grid>
    <Grid.Resources>
       <local:DataContextProxy x:Key="proxy" Data="{Binding}" />
     </Grid.Resources>

    <esri:Map>
        <esri:ArcGISTiledMapServiceLayer Url="http://services.arcgisonline.com/ArcGIS/rest/services/World_Imagery/MapServer" /> 
        <esri:GraphicsLayer ID="MyGraphicsLayer"
                GraphicsSource="{Binding Path=Data.AllGrahics, Source={StaticResource proxy}}" />
    </esri:Map>

    <YourControl DataContext="{Binding Path=Data.SelectedGraphics, Source= {StaticResource proxy}}"/>
</Grid>
```

Then you can direct SelectedGraphic set to ViewModel from code-behind or from Xaml. In simpler cases I usually just invoke some ViewModel behavior from the code-behind. I keep this in View to encapsulate mouse controlling and not bloat the ViewModel for chancing event handlers from view. In more complex cases I have MapService (or MapController) class that encapsulates the Map behavior (and event handling mess) and this gets to injected to the ViewModel to make working with Map a bit easier.

To use SelectedGraphic property in View, you can just data bind that to another control like any other property and if you want, you can access attributes with `{Binding Attributes[nameOfTheAttribute]}` notation if the data context is set to `SelectedGraphic` in that scope.